# Power Bi API push data to an existsing dataset from Power BI Desktop

Tags: rest, powerbi

I was able to create a dataset and push data to it via an application by **Power BI Rest API**.
Now I have a dataset that I have imported from **.pbix** file (Power BI Desktop). Can I push data to it via **Power BI Rest API**? I have tried it and I always get an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that REST APIs can only manipulate the datasets and tables also created via REST APIs.

You can check this idea [Push data via API into an existing model](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas?query=push%20data%20rest%20api) and vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Push dataset you are using a live connection, which means you can only have one PushDataset in your .pbix report.

Pushing data with REST API applies only to push datasets.

*** this is true at the moment. Might change in future updates of PowerBi.